Quotation marks or italics depending on the speaker having said, vs. mouthed, vs imagined, etc
Quotation marks or italics?

He said, "I love you."
He mouthed, I love you.

June asked a similar question back on November 8, but she got no responses. I'm inclined to go with quotation marks, but I would appreciate hearing others' opinions.

I don't think there is any rule about this. I'm sure quotation marks would be fine.

In literate writing, it's common to use different orthographies to distinguish spoken words from thoughts and other non-verbal use of language. In other contexts, we usually just use quotes for everything.

This question is similar to: Is it direct speech?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. User 184 ... cites 'A thought can either be written between quotation marks or written in italics', with reference. I doubt you'll find an extension to mouthing, but surely there can't be yet another rfeinement.

I'm having trouble finding the November 8 question. If this one is not substantially different, please just rely on the old one. Depending on reputation score, one can post a "bounty" on an old question to attract attention. Meanwhile: SE's question-and-answer format is not just about discussing opinions but giving solid answers. This is a style question and can vary from one style guide or author to another.
